# MERGE INTO table containing AUTO_INCREMENT columns

Tags: sql, h2, sql-merge

I've declared the following table for use by audit triggers:

```
CREATE TABLE audit_transaction_ids (id IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, uuid VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL, `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
```

1. The trigger will get invoked multiple times in the same transaction.
2. The first time the trigger is invoked, I want it to insert a new
   row with the current TRANSACTION_ID() and time.
3. The subsequent times the trigger is invoked, I want it to return
   the existing "id" (I invoke Statement.getGeneratedKeys() to that end)
   without altering "uuid" or "time".

The current schema seems to have two problems.

1. When I invoke `MERGE INTO audit_transaction_ids (uuid, time) KEY(id) VALUES(TRANSACTION_ID(), NOW())` I get: `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "ID" contains null values; SQL
   statement: MERGE INTO audit_transaction_ids (uuid, time) KEY(id) VALUES
   (TRANSACTION_ID(), NOW()) [90081-155]`
2. I suspect that invoking MERGE on an existing row will alter "time".

How do I fix both these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MERGE` is analogous to `java.util.Map.put(key, value)`: it will insert the row if it doesn't exist, and update the row if it does. That being said, you can still merge into a table containing `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns so long as you use another column as the key.

Given `customer[id identity, email varchar(30), count int]` you could `merge into customer(id, email, count) key(email) values((select max(id) from customer c2 where c2.email='test@acme.com'), 'test@acme.com', 10)`. Meaning, re-use the id if a record exists, use null otherwise.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/18819879/14731 for a portable way to insert-or-update depending on whether a row already exists.

---

**1. MERGE INTO audit_transaction_ids (uuid, time) KEY(id) VALUES(TRANSACTION_ID(), NOW())**

If you just want to insert a new row, use:
`INSERT INTO audit_transaction_ids (uuid, time) VALUES(TRANSACTION_ID(), NOW())`

`MERGE` without setting the value for the column `ID` doesn't make sense if `ID` is used as the key, because that way it could never (even in theory) update an existing rows. What you could do is using another key column (in the case above there is no column that could be used). See the documentation for `MERGE` for details.

**2. Invoking MERGE on an existing row will alter "time"**

I'm not sure if you talk about the fact that the value of the column 'time' is altered. This is the expected behavior if you use `MERGE ... VALUES(.., NOW())`, because the `MERGE` statement is supposed to update that column.

Or maybe you mean that older versions of H2 returned different values within the same transaction (unlike most other databases, which return the same value within the same transaction). This is true, however with H2 version 1.3.155 (2011-05-27) and later, this incompatibility is fixed. See also the [change log](http://www.h2database.com/html/changelog.html): "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and so on now return the same value within a transaction." It looks like this is not the problem in your case, because you do seem to use version 1.3.155 (the error message [90081-155] includes the build / version number).

Comment: @Thomas: forgetting my specific schema for a moment, I thought the purpose of MERGE is to INSERT if the row is missing or UPDATE if it exists. As such, how are you supposed to MERGE INTO a table that contains an AUTO_INCREMENT column? Am I misunderstanding the purpose of MERGE INTO?

Comment: `MERGE` is useful if you don't know whether the rows already exists. Usually that means you don't have an auto-increment primary key. If you know that a given row doesn't exist, then use `INSERT`. If you know it exists, use `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Thomas: So if I don't know if the row exists ahead of time, it is impossible to use MERGE with AUTO_INCREMENT columns?

Comment: @Gili To update a row, you obviously need to know _which_ row to update. So you need to know the primary key of the table (or another unique key). But in your example the unique key seems to be `id` and you didn't supply the value in the `values` clause. So how could the database know _which_ row to update?

Comment: @Thomas: I'd want the query to locate the row containing a specific "uuid". If no such row exists, insert one. Otherwise, return the associated id. How would I implement that?

Comment: That's definitely not what `MERGE` is meant for. I suggest to do a `SELECT` and if required an `INSERT`.

Comment: @Thomas: Okay I'll do that. For the sake of resolving the question, can you please provide a detailed explanation of what `MERGE` is meant for?

Comment: @Gili `MERGE` is analogous to `java.util.Map.put(key, value)`: it will insert the row if it doesn't exist, and update the row if it does (this analogy doesn't include the returned value however). See also the Wikipedia entry for Upsert.

Comment: @Thomas: So if I understand you (and Wikipedia) correctly, `MERGE` always requires one to specify the primary key value. Since it doesn't really make sense to specify the key value for auto_increment columns, it doesn't really make sense to use `MERGE` for tables containing them. Is that correct?

Comment: You can specify the key for auto_increment columns, for example if you want to import data (when loading the database). But supplying NULL when using MERGE doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

MERGE INTO AUDIT_TRANSACTION_IDS (uuid, time) KEY (uuid, time) 
 VALUES (TRANSACTION_ID(), NOW());

<sub>little performance tip: make sure uuid is indexed</sub>

**Long Answer:**

`MERGE` is basically an `UPDATE` which `INSERT`s when no record found to be updated.

Wikipedia gives a more concise, standardized syntax of 
[MERGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29) but you have to supply your own update and insert. 
 (Whether this will be supported in H2 or not is not mine to answer)

So how do you update a record using `MERGE` in H2? You define a key to be looked up for, if it is found you update the row (with column names you supply, and you can define `DEFAULT` here, to reset your columns to its defaults), otherwise you insert the row.

Now what is `Null`? `Null` means unknown, not found, undefined, anything which is not what you're looking for.

That is why `Null` works as key to be looked up for. Because it means the record is not found.

> MERGE INTO table1 (id, col1, col2)
>   KEY(id) VALUES (Null, 1, 2)

`Null` has a value. it IS a value.

Now let's see your SQL.

> MERGE INTO table1 (id, col1, col2)
>   KEY(id) VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 2)

What is that implying? To me, it says 
 I have this [DEFAULT, 1, 2], ***find me a `DEFAULT` in column `id`***, 
 then update `col1` to 1, `col2` to 2, if found. 
 otherwise, insert default to `id`, 1 to `col1`, 2 to `col2`.

See what I emphasized there? What does that even mean? What is `DEFAULT`? How do you compare `DEFAULT` to `id`?

`DEFAULT` is just a keyword.

You can do stuff like,

> MERGE INTO table1 (id, col1,
>   timeStampCol) KEY(id) VALUES (Null, 1,
>   DEFAULT)

but don't put DEFAULT in the key column.

Comment: please add a discussion of MERGE INTO's return value. Can Statement.getGeneratedKeys() be used to retrieve any keys?