# QueryDSL: How to SELECT literals as part of a SQLSubQuery?

Tags: querydsl

How do I implement https://stackoverflow.com/a/16392399/14731 using QueryDSL SQL?

I understand that

> new SQLSubQuery().from(customer).where(customer.email.eq("foo@example.com"))

models

> select customer where customer.email = 'foo@example.com'

but I don't understand how to **select [literal]** such as:

`select 1 from customer` or
`select 'foo@example.com', 0`

as required by the aforementioned link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is ok to use parameters then using constants should work

```
new SQLSubQuery().from(customer)
  .where(customer.email.eq("foo@example.com"))
  .list(Expressions.constant("foo@example.com"),
        Expressions.constant(0))
```

`Expressions.constant` is documented here http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.3/apidocs/com/mysema/query/support/Expressions.html#constant%28T%29

Comment: What do you mean `if it is ok to use parameters`? What parameters does the above introduce?

Comment: Parameters in prepared statements, your example has literals encoded into SQL.

Comment: 1. So you're saying that your solution sets parameters in a `PreparedStatement` instead of injecting literals into the SQL directly? 2. Does QueryDSL support injecting literals into the statement, or does it only support the use of `PreparedStatement` parameters?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. You can inject SQL snippets via TemplateExpression instances, but there is no automatic conversion/escaping of generic constants to SQL inline literals