# QueryDSL: How to insert or update?

Tags: h2, querydsl

I'm trying to implement https://stackoverflow.com/a/16392399/14731 for a table called "Modules" using QueryDSL. Here is my query:

```
String newName = "MyModule";
QModules modules = QModules.modules;
BooleanExpression moduleNotExists = session.subQuery().
    from(modules).where(modules.name.eq(newName)).notExists();
SimpleSubQuery<String> setModuleName = session.subQuery().
    where(moduleNotExists).unique(Expressions.constant(newName));
long moduleId = session.insert(modules).set(modules.name, setModuleName).
    executeWithKey(modules.id);
```

I am expecting this to translate into:

```
insert into modules(name)
select 'MyModule'
where not exists
(select 1 from modules where modules.name = 'MyModule')
```

Instead, I am getting:

```
NULL not allowed for column "NAME"; SQL statement:
   insert into MODULES (NAME)
   values ((select ?
   from dual
   where not exists (select 1
   from MODULES MODULES
   where MODULES.NAME = ?)))
```

where `?` is equal to `MyModule`.

1. Why does QueryDSL insert `from dual`? I am expecting it to omit `from` altogether.
2. How do I fix this query?

Comment: Here is the related ticket https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/510

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the insert into select form use

```
columns(...).select(...)
```

But your error suggests that the INSERT clause is valid, but semantically not what you want.

Using `InsertClause.set(...)` you don't get the conditional insertion you are aiming for.

In other words with

```
columns(...).select(...)
```

you map the full result set into an INSERT template and no rows will be inserted for empty result sets, but with

```
set(...)
```

you map query results to a single column of an INSERT template and null values will be used for empty results.